# I am having trouble delivering images in a mms messages using a url stored on Imgur. Anyone else experiencing this problem?

Tags: image, imgur

I am using a excel template to send multiple text messages. One of the columns contains an url form Imgur. The messages with images have been displaying fine until a couple of days ago. The images that I have previously used on Twilio  are now not being delivered. I have tried the same images that have been delivered before. Please let me know if have run into this problem.